# Homeomorphism mapping boundary sphere of a ball into ball implies mapping ball into ball?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:\mathbf V_1\cong\mathbf {V}_2$ be a homeomorphism of finite dimensional real vector spaces (with norm topologies). Let $\mathbb B_1\subset \mathbf V_1$ be the inclusion of a disk/ball (not necessarily open, i.e not of full dimension). Let $\mathbb S_1=\partial \mathbb B_1$ be its boundary sphere.

**Question 1.** Suppose $f$ maps the sphere into a disk/ball in $\mathbf V_2$ i.e $f(\mathbb S_1)\subset \mathbb B_2$. Does it follow that $f(\mathbb B_1)\subset \mathbb B_2$?

**Question 2.** Does the above follow if $f$ is an isometry with respect to the induced metrics?

Comment: It is not perfectly clear to me what your setup is. Is your Ball supposed to be in some plane? Or how is your not-full-dimension ball supposed to look like? Do you take standard balls around $0$ or is it a ball around an arbitrary point $x$?

Comment: The first is false as you can bend horizontal lines so that two discs, the horizontal and the bent one, will only touch each other's boundaries. If in the second you still assume $f$ to be homeo then this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem